# Как сгенерировать пользовательские токены для запросов к vk api

Tags: python, api, вконтакте, token

Использую Python.

Пытаюсь обойди ограничение vk api users.search в 1000 человек. Идея решения использовать vk api exec.

Для этого использую vk_api.VkFunction

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.execute import VkFunction
user_token='token here'

def exec_string(year):
api = f"API.users.search({{'count':1000, 'city':133, 'birth_month':1, 'birth_year':{year}, 'has_photo':1,'sex':2, " \
      f"'fields':'city, sex', 'status':6}})"
for i in range(2, 13):
    api += f", API.users.search({{'count':1000, 'city':133, 'birth_month':{i}, 'birth_year':{year}, 'has_photo':1," \
           f"'sex':2, 'fields':'city, sex', 'status':6}})"

return f"return [{api}];"


for year in range(2000, 2007):
    code = exec_string(year)
    result = VkFunction(code=code)

for item in result(vk_api.VkApi(token=user_token).get_api()):
    print(item)
```

Данное решение позволяет получить сведения о пользователях в промежутке за 7 лет, можно довести до 14, дальше идет ограничение и с одним токеном больше не вытащить. Знаю, что можно сгенерировать токены, упоминание об этом в этой [статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/529696/).

**Вопрос:** Как генерировать токены имея только одну пару login_vk, password_vk ?